# Samsung Galaxy A23 stuck on Download Mode; cannot verify vbmeta image after I tried locking the bootloader

Tags: samsung, bootloader-lock, download-mode

I am using a Samsung Galaxy A23. I noticed my phone's bootloader was unlocked, so I tried to lock it while in download mode. But it is stuck there and gives an error verifying vbmeta image.

Please help.

Comment: That means your installed system fails the Android Verified Boot check. vbmeta contains the hashes of your system partitions. You can only try to install an official full firmware image using Odin/Heimdal.